# How to fail Spring application startup if AOP Pointcut expression was not matched?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have 2 datasources in my Spring Boot app. Whenever I take a connection and there is a user's principal within Security Context, I would like to set user's id in the context of database package by invoking procedure.

To achieve this I created an AOP advice like this:

```
@Configuration
@Aspect
class SqlAuthAopConfig {

    @AfterReturning(
            value = "bean(myDataSource) && execution(java.sql.Connection javax.sql.DataSource+.getConnection(..))",
            returning = "connection")
    fun initUser(connection: Connection) {

        val principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.principal as? MyUser ?: return

        connection.prepareStatement("BEGIN P_AUTH.SET_ID(?);END;").use { ps ->
            ps.setLong(1, principal.id)
            ps.execute()
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I used `beans` pointcut designator (because I have 2 datasources). This does not seem to be type-safe. If DS bean name will change in future, the pointcut expression won't match any bean, but the app will be silently started. How can I configure this aspect to fail application startup if pointcut expression was not matched?

Comment: It is ugly, but maybe you can add a static block to your aspect class and query the bean in it by name. If it cannot be found, throw an exception with a corresponding message. If that helps, let me know (I don't use Spring) and I can turn the comment into an answer. As an alternative, think about how to differentiate the two DS from each other by something other than the bean name. Maybe they have different types, package names or implement different interfaces. Then use that information in your pointcut.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@AfterThrowing` spring annotation then you can intercept by following way:

```
@AfterThrowing(value = "bean(...) && execution(...)", throwing = "ex")
public void interceptDataSourceErrors(Exception ex) {
    // Doing something here with exception.
    logger.debug( ex.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?